# Getting count of occurrences in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a backend where I can create a Poll.  Within a Poll I can create a PollQuestion.  And for a PollQuestion, I can create many PollAnswer's.

If I do something like this in my Controller

```
$poll = DB::table('poll')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
$question = DB::table('poll_question')->where('poll_id', $poll->id)->first();
$answers = DB::table('poll_answer')->select('answer')->where('question_id', $question->id)->get();

print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($answers);
print_r("</pre>");
```

I can see an output like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [answer] => Answer 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [answer] => Answer 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [answer] => Answer 3
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [answer] => Answer 4
        )

)
```

So, the above Poll was given 4 possible answers to the PollQuestion.

Now I have a frontend which displays the question, and a radio button for each PollAnswer.  When they select one and save, I get a PollResponse.  If I do something like this

```
$pollResponses = DB::table('poll_response')->select('response')->where('poll_id', $poll->id)->get();
```

The output might be something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => Answer 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => Answer 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => Answer 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => Answer 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => Answer 3
        )
)
```

So I can see what people have selected.  Now, for each possible PollAnswer, I need to count the number of PollResponse which relate to it.  So for the above data, I should get something like

```
1 = 1
2 = 1
3 = 1
4 = 3
```

Is there any easy way I can do this in Laravel, or would I need to loop both the Answers and Responses to get the individual counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any laravel-specific solution, but you can always push the responses to a separate array and then use the php function `array_count_values($array)` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on the new array.

```
$newArray = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($pollResponses); $i++){
    array_push($newArray, $pollResponses[$i]->response);
};

$count = array_count_values($newArray);
```

It will return a two dimensional array with the answer as the key and the number of times it occurs as the value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using models,you can do this in Laravel

```
$polls = Poll::with(['questions.answers'])->get();
```

Your Poll.php file

```
...
class Poll extends Model{
    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Your Question.php file

```
...
class Question extends Model{
    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

And then in your view file (assuming it's .blade.php)

```
@foreach($polls as $poll)
    @foreach($poll->questions as $question)
        {{ $question->title }}
        <ul>
            @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                <li>{{ $answer->title }} </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```